# Isomorphism $\operatorname{Ext}(B,A) \cong H^1(\mathfrak{g}, \operatorname{Hom}(B,A))$

Tags: lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am giving a talk on Lie Algebra Cohomology, more specifically on the first and second Whitehead Lemma. My problem is that I don't quite understand the proof of the isomorphism $$\operatorname{Ext}(B,A) \cong H^1(\mathfrak{g}, \operatorname{Hom}(B,A))$$
$A,B$ being $\mathfrak{g}$-Modules,
which is proved in Hilgert and Neebs Book *Structure and Geometry of Lie Groups*. 
In particular I don't understand why different sections lead to cohomologous cocyles and why this leads to the afore mentioned isomorphism.

Comment: See Theorem $1.2.6$ in my [lecture notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_17_lie_coho_course.pdf). The proof may be similar of the one in Hilgert and Neeb. It has all necessary details, though (well, in German, but most of it are formulas anyway). Did you try to look it up in Weibel's book?

Comment: Thanks a lot, your script contains exactly what I need and in german too.